# Include different objects with same name from libraries with same name.

Tags: javascript, html, conflicting-libraries

I am attempting to create a page with feeds from multiple network cameras, but the JS libraries I reference are stored on the cameras themselves with the same name. Also, the video stream viewer objects are named identically.

Here's a sample of the code I have so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.0.1:80/jsv/SncViewer.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new SNC.viewer('div1',{sz:'3',atc:'0',at:'1',ptz:'1',fps:'30',mt:'1',iPS:'1',frm:'0'});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.0.2:80/jsv/SncViewer.js'></script>
<script>
new SNC.viewer('div2',{sz:'3',atc:'0',at:'1',ptz:'1',fps:'30',mt:'1',iPS:'1',frm:'0'});
</script>
```

It displays the first object correctly, but not the second.

Is there a way to create separate instances of this object that come from the different network libraries?

Comment: So it's the same library basically but each one thinking that itself would be a global singleton instance? I fear if the above code does not work and you don't want to rewrite/fix the camera library you only can show the two feeds in different iframes.

Comment: Do the two SncViewer.js files having different content?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't have access to the camera libraries, and these are in a frame already. Picture a 2x2 array of video streams using frames, then each frame cycles through a certain set of cameras using show/hide div. This code is in each frame.

Comment: Purnil: Yes, apparently each SncViewer.js internally specifies where to source the video stream. In the parameters to the object I'm only changing autoplay, size, fps etc. not specifying the data source.

Comment: You can easily download the scripts by pasting the URLs into the location bar of your browser. It will then either display the script or save it on disk.

Comment: If you're using frames anyway, you should use one frame per camera and push the frames around in your array, not multiple cameras in a single frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is probably to download the JavaScript from both cameras and examine it. They probably hard-code some data in them but maybe you can create your own version which allows to configure the SNC viewer object at runtime.

If that fails or is too much effort, then put each camera into a new `iframe` because frames will isolate the scripts from each other.